# Querying Zulu Times in MySql

Tags: mysql

I have events saved in my database which are saved using the date format below.

```
'2013-09-12T12:14:18Z'
```

I am trying to get these events using the query below, which returns an empty result set.

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE event_time BETWEEN '2013_09-12T12:13:16Z' AND '2013_09-12T12:15:16Z'
```

Is there a way to somehow search these records?

Comment: what is the data type of event_time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've stored dates as strings, your query is basically an alphabetical lookup (just like a dictionary). As such, comparing `2013_` with `2013-` cannot render the "expected" result.

Solutions:

- Fix the column type
- Convert column to actual date inside the query
- Always use the same format: `2013-...Z`